# Import title of files containing string into a text document using batch

Tags: string, batch-file, find

I am trying to create a batch script that imports the titles of text files in a folder that contain a specific string into a new test file.

This is what I have achieved so far. It imports every text file into the document and if it contains the string, it will put the contents of that file under the title. I just want the title of the file to be imported. Thank you

`find "test" dir *.txt > output.txt`

OUTPUT:

```
---------- ALSO_CONTAINS.TXT
test.

---------- CONTAINS.TXT
This is a test

---------- CONTAINS_ASWELL.TXT
This is also a test

---------- SHOULD_FAIL.TXT
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [find](/questions/tagged/find), use [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) instead, which if you read the usage information from `findstr /?` at the Command Prompt, will show you a `/M` option, *(which prints only the filename if it contains a match)*

```bat
FindStr /IM "test" *.txt>output.txt
```

Just in case there's an issue with your `%PATH%` and/or `%PATHEXT%` environment variables, you could also use:

```bat
"%__APPDIR__%FindStr.exe" /IM "test" "*.txt">"output.txt"
```